# Java library to partially export a database while respecting referential integrity constraints

Tags: java, database

My production database is several GB's uncompressed and it's getting to be a pain to download and run locally when trying to reproduce a bug or test a feature with real data.

I would like to be able to select the specific records that interest me, then have the library figure out what other records are necessary to produce a dataset that respects the databases integrity constraints and finally print it out as a list of insert statements or dump that I can restore.

For example:

- given Author, Blog and Comment tables
- when I select comments posted after a certain date
- I should get inserts for the Blog records the comments have foreign keys to and the Author records those Blogs have foreign keys to.

Answer (score 6):

this looks like what you look for [Jailer](http://jailer.sourceforge.net/)

It exports consistent, referentially intact row-sets from relational databases.

Comment: Jailer is an exceptional tool, I've used it again and again to test on a subset of a very large databese. It's very simple and very easy to use yet powerful, and so useful, provided you have designed your db with referential integrity constraints.