# Generate data for an application

Tags: database

If your planing to build an application but you don't have enough data to fill a database, how you will generate some ?

Do you know any application which can generate data based on some criterias and export it later in MySQL database?

Thanks :)

Comment: http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/mysql/datagenerator

Comment: http://www.turbodata.ca/overview02.htm

Comment: @Zaki Why didn't you think of writing them up as answers to this? Anyways thanks for the answers. I can finally search with this term "data generators".

Answer (score 0):

I always try to fill DB with some real data, related to the subject. So I can see, how the data will be faced to user.
Of course, if you want to run performance tests, you should generate some random data.

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to a production db with real data, then look at this [Java library to partially export a database while respecting referential integrity constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400199/java-library-to-partially-export-a-database-while-respecting-referential-integrit/2400209#2400209)